# New single posts do not have the same styling as the first Wordpress post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

For some reason, the only "single" post that is properly styled is the first sample post. When I add a new post, my sidebar displays underneath the content and my comments section doesnt display at all.

Here is the first "Default" post (hello world) that I edited with my new content and is properly styled:

[image: correct layout]

Here is what it looks like on the second post (which is incorrect) and the comments section isn't even displayed.

[image: incorrect layout]

Here is my `single.php`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section id="single-post-feed" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="article-container">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-page', get_post_format() ); 

            the_post_navigation();

            // moved the comments_template() to content-page.php

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

    </div>

</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And `content-page.php`

```
<?php

//Advanced custom Fields
$song_lyrics = get_field('song_lyrics');
$artist_name = get_field('artist_name');
$song_title = get_field('song_title');
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <div class="album-artwork-single-post">
        <div class="album-overlay">
            <div class="media-play-btn-container" id="play-pause-toggle">
                <div class="play-pause-ring"></div>
                <a id="media-toggle" href=""><i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="artist-track-title-container">
                <div class="artist-name-heading">
                    <?php echo $artist_name ?>
                </div>
                <div class="track-name-heading">
                    <?php echo $song_title ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-artwork">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-section">
        <div class="curator-profile-pic-overlay">
            <div class="curator-pic-container">
                                <?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID'), '64'); ?>
                                <?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID'), '80'); ?>
                <!-- <img class="curator-prof-pic" src="" alt="Profile Picture"> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-curator-container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  dig-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span><span class="dig-text">Dig</span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  download-btn"><span class="download-text">Download</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-container">
            <div class="curator-alias">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle verified-check"></i><?php the_author();?>
            </div>
            <div class="curator-class">Curator </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="horiz-sep-bar"></div>
    <div class="the-review">
        <div class="the-review-header">
            WHAT CURATORS ARE SAYING
        </div>
        <div class="the-review-content">
                    <?php
                        the_content();

                        wp_link_pages( array(
                            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'uncvrd' ),
                            'after'  => '</div>',
                        ) );
                    ?> <span class="curator-credit"> &#58;&#58;  <a class="curator-username" href="#"><?php the_author();?></a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="post-genre-boxes">
                    <?php
                    foreach(get_the_category() as $category)
                    {
                            echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary post-genre"><span class="post-genre-text"> '.$category->cat_name.'</span></button></a>';
                    }
                    ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horiz-sep-bar"></div>
    <div class="lyrics-container">
        <button class="lyrics-button">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" id="lyric-toggle" href="#collapse1"><i class="icon ion-chevron-down"></i>LYRICS</a>
        </button>

        <div class="lyrics-content" id="lyrics-dropdown">

            <?php echo $song_lyrics ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horiz-sep-bar"></div>
    <div class="horiz-sep-bar-white"></div>
    <div class="artist-hub">
        <div class="artist-profile-pic">
            <div class="prof-pic-container">
                <img class="sc-prof-pic" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000280531684-6vslia-t500x500.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-track-title">
            ABOUT "<?php echo $song_title ?>"
        </div>
        <div class="artist-name-hub">
            <?php echo $artist_name ?>
        </div>
        <div class="track-details">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima minus tempore distinctio asperiores voluptatum, hic doloremque ipsum! Perspiciatis ratione aliquam quis porro aliquid provident hic, reprehenderit, voluptates quas? Magnam, facere.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            <div class="stats-socials-container">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-bolt balanced"></i>
                <div class="total-number-digs">14,395</div>
                <div class="artist-social-buttons">
                    <a href=""><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="icon ion-social-instagram"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ad-box-above-comments">
        <div class="ad-box">
            <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
            <!-- UNCVRD Website -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-2215550501221227" data-ad-slot="9389394438" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
            <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
                        <?php
                            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                                comments_template();
                            endif;
                        ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <section id="side-bar">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </section>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Let me know what else you need and I can update the post, thanks!

Comment: have you checked you div properly closed?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj good question. Looks like the closing div right above the sidebar section isnt linked to anything on the `content-page.php` however when I take it out of the document, both the original post (which was initially styled properly) and the second post both have the sidebar issue. Second post still doesnt have comments section either

Comment: can you provide both posts link please ?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj currently developing on localhost, can I zippyshare the php files to you?

Comment: This zippyshare contains the Wordpress theme I'm developing called "uncvrd" let me know if you have any questions: http://www66.zippyshare.com/v/1t30CjNZ/file.html @RajKumarBhardwaj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131398/discussion-between-jordan-lewallen-and-raj-kumar-bhardwaj).